# How to use group_by_value to create batches in benthos

Tags: benthos

I have been trying to understand how to batch things in benthos but am a bit confused on how to do it..

Take this example:

```
input:
  generate:
    interval: ""
    count: 40
    mapping: |
      root = count("test")

pipeline:
  processors:
    - log:    
        level: INFO
        message: 'Test! ${! (this) } ${! (this % 2 == 0) } ${! batch_size() }'
    - group_by_value:
        value: ${! (this % 2 == 0) }
    - archive:
        format: tar
    - compress:
        algorithm: gzip

output:
  file:
    path: test/${! (this % 2 == 0) }.tar.gz
    codec: all-bytes
```

My expectation with this would be 2 files in test/.. one called "true.tar" and another called "false.tar", with 20 elements each, (odd and even numbers). What I get instead is a single file with the last message. I understand from the logs that it is not actually batching these based on that condition

I thought group_by_value would kind of create "two streams/batches" of messages that would get separately handled in the output/archive, but it looks like it doesn't behave like that

Could you please help me understand how it works?

additionally, I was also going to limit the size of each of these streams to a certain number, so each would get their number of entries in the TAR limited

Thanks!!

EDIT 1

This is something which works more like expected, but this was I have to "know" how many items I want to batch before actually being able to filter them.. I wonder if I can't just "accumulate" things based on this group_by_value condition and batch them based on a count later?

```
input:
  broker:
    inputs:
      - generate:
          interval: ""
          count: 40
          mapping: |
            root = count("test")
    batching: 
      count: 40

pipeline:
  processors:
    - group_by_value:
        value: ${! (this % 2 == 0) }
    - log:    
        level: INFO
        message: 'Test! ${! (this) } ${! (this % 2 == 0) } ${! batch_size() }'
    - bloblang: |
        meta name = (this) % 2 == 0
    - archive:
        format: tar
        path: ${! (this) }

output:
  file:
    path: test/${! (meta("name")) }.tar
    codec: all-bytes
```

Comment: by the way the log in the snippet is coming before the group_by_part but it does the same after it

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, [`group_by_value`](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/processors/group_by_value) operates on message batches, which is why your first example produces a single file as output. In fact, it produces a file for each message, but since the file name is identical, each new file ends up overwriting the previous one.

From your edit, I'm not sure I get what you're trying to achieve. The [batch policy](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/configuration/batching/#batch-policy) documentation explains that `byte_size`, `count` and `period` are the available conditions for composing batches. When either of those is met, a batch is flushed, so you don't necessarily have to rely on a specific count. For convenience, the `batching` policy also has a [`processors` field](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/configuration/batching/#post-batch-processing), which allows you to define an optional list of processors to apply to each batch before it is flushed.

The [windowed processing](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/configuration/windowed_processing) documentation might also be of interest, since it explains how the [`system_window` buffer](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/buffers/system_window) can be used to chop a stream of messages into tumbling or sliding windows of fixed temporal size. It has a section on grouping [here](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/configuration/windowed_processing#grouping).

Update 22.02.2022: Here's an example of how to perform output batching based on some key, as requested in the comments:

```yaml
input:
  generate:
    interval: "500ms"
    count: 9
    mapping: |
      root.key = if count("key_counter") % 3 == 0 {
        "foo"
      } else {
        "bar"
      }
      root.content = uuid_v4()

pipeline:
  processors:
    - bloblang: |
        root = this
        # 3 is the number of messages you'd like to have in the "foo" batch.
        root.foo_key_end = this.key == "foo" && count("foo_key_counter") % 3 == 0

output:
  broker:
    outputs:
      - stdout: {}
        processors:
          - group_by_value:
              value: ${! json("key") }
          - bloblang: |
              root = this
              root.foo_key_end = deleted()
              root.batch_size = batch_size()
              root.batch_index = batch_index()

    batching:
      # Something big so, unless something bad happens, you should see enough
      # messages with key = "foo" before reaching this number
      count: 1000
      check: this.foo_key_end
```

Sample output:

```sh
> benthos --log.level error -c config_group_by.yaml 
{"batch_index":0,"batch_size":3,"content":"84e51d8b-a4e0-42c8-8cbb-13a8b7b37823","key":"foo"}
{"batch_index":1,"batch_size":3,"content":"1b35ff8b-7121-426e-8447-11e834610b90","key":"foo"}
{"batch_index":2,"batch_size":3,"content":"a9d9c661-1068-447f-9324-c418b0d7de9d","key":"foo"}

{"batch_index":0,"batch_size":6,"content":"5c9d26aa-f1dc-46ae-9845-3b035c1e569e","key":"bar"}
{"batch_index":1,"batch_size":6,"content":"17bbc7c1-94ec-4c9e-b0c5-b9c11f18498f","key":"bar"}
{"batch_index":2,"batch_size":6,"content":"7d7b9621-e174-4ca2-8a2e-1679e8177335","key":"bar"}
{"batch_index":3,"batch_size":6,"content":"db24273f-7064-498e-9914-9dd4c671dcd7","key":"bar"}
{"batch_index":4,"batch_size":6,"content":"4cfbea0e-dcc4-4d84-a87f-6930dd797737","key":"bar"}
{"batch_index":5,"batch_size":6,"content":"d6cb4726-4796-444d-91df-a5c278860106","key":"bar"}
```

Comment: thanks for the response @Mihai! what I was trying to achieve is getting batches based on some key.. and only flush it if the count (for example) reaches 50k messages for a specific key, and not "any 50k mssages", and THEN i would group by key (which would deliver <50k messages per key).. does that make it clearer?

Comment: @pimguilherme I provided a sample config which I believe achieves what you're looking to get. The reason I added `count: 1000` in the batching was to ensure that the batches are eventually released even if you don't get enough messages with `key` set to `foo`. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks again @Mihai! it looks very interesting.. one of the requisites would be to additionally also batch "bar" in chunks of 3, so we would have in total 3 batches here.. (1 foo batch and 2 bar batches), but that doesn't sound so simple because at some point we would have to flush the batch based on some "generic" counter and possibly some of the batches would be incomplete, right.. or else we could just dismiss the counter and flush it as soon as we have "complete batches".. hmm

Comment: You're welcome! I think maybe it can be done with the `switch` output, where the cases are outputs of type `broker`, or something like that, but it's starting to get a bit unwieldy and I'm wondering if there might be a more generic pattern that I'm not aware of. If you have some time, please open an issue on https://github.com/Jeffail/benthos explaining the limitations you're seeing with my solution and the maintainer, Ash, will chime in. He's also active on Discord / Slack: https://www.benthos.dev/community if you'd prefer to chat through various options.